How do I find out from Google what APIs I'm using that may be affected by an upcoming OAuth consent change?
I got an email from Google saying:
"Hello Google Developer,
Our records indicate that your app(s) has requested access to Google APIs and may be affected by an upcoming OAuth consent change..."
How can I learn what those records say about the specific endpoints my app is using that will be affected? I'd like to verify that these records are correct, and see in-code where I'm using them.
Thanks
I tried to learn the details from the email, but they aren't in it.

You should check the docs on all the apis you are using that's just a form letter you won't get any more information from them

The OAuth granular permission changes apply to API calls to Google authorization endpoint. It is when your apps request users to grant permissions to access users' Google data on their behalf. There are various ways to call the API. They can be called directly or through various SDKs. It would be up to your implementation. You can check what permissions (scopes) your applications request in the OAuth consent screen page in Google Cloud Console.
Thanks
